# special characters/emoji assignment issue in swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am following the audacity code . The following line throws error in Xcode.

```
let translations = [String : String]()
    override init() {
        super.init()

        translations["heart"] = "\u{0001F496}"
        translations["fish"] = "\u{E522}"
  }
```

both translations assignment lines are throwing error "*cannot assign to the result of this expression*"

Can you kindly advise what is the issue with the code above?

Comment: You need `var translations` so that your dictionary is mutable.

Comment: @misguided what is audacity code? did you make it to traslate emoji?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let translations = [String : String]()` makes `translations` immutable. Use `var` instead.